# Rails staging migration environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I upgraded from Rails 5.0 to Rails 5.2 for an app. In the staging environment, I get the following error upon deploy

```
18:34:09 rake aborted!
18:34:09 ArgumentError: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'staging_migration' environment, set this string with `rails credentials:edit`
```

Is `staging_migration` a new environment that has been introduced since Rails 5.1/5.2 ? I never encountered this before. I am planning to create a new secret for this. Besides staging, should I also create one for `production_migration` ?

Comment: What rake task are you running that caused this error?

Comment: not sure. it is part of a deploy script. I will see if I can find more info